# C change the indices representation of an array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I want to use char to represent an array
say I have a

```
char arrays[50]={"hello", "world"};
```

instead of the zero index representing the first string I want a letter to represent it,
I know that this can be done in java with a hash table
is this possible in c

I am thinking of using an array of pointers to refer to each string
but I have no idea how to implement it in a large array as I have just started learning the use of pointers
something like

```
char *a:
arrays[0]=&a;
```

Comment: what is your question..ur question is very unclear..what do you want to know

Comment: you can use a map like in Java and get integers as values.

Comment: Is it a mapping between a `char` and a `char*` that is required?

Comment: `arrays` is not an array of strings but an array of single characters, therefore the declaration as you posted it is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a mapping between a `char` and a string (`char*`) that is required you could create a simple `struct` that contains the pair:

```
struct entry
{
    char key;
    const char* value;
};
```

If the content of the map is known at compile time then:

```
const struct entry map[] =
    {
        { 'a', "a.text" },
        { 'b', "b.text" },
        { 'c', "c.text" },
        { 'd', "d.text" },
        { 'e', "e.text" }
    };
```

by keeping the entries ordered you can use [`bsearch()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch) to locate an entry:

```
int compare(const void* l, const void* r)
{
    const struct entry* ll = (const struct entry*)l;
    const struct entry* rr = (const struct entry*)r;

    return ll->key - rr->key;
}

struct entry find = { 'd' };

struct entry* e = bsearch(&find,
                          map,
                          sizeof(map)/sizeof(map[0]),
                          sizeof(map[0]),
                          compare);

if (e)
{
    printf("{%c, %s}\n", e->key, e->value);
}
else
{
    printf("Not found\n");
}
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/x6roRm .

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
char *arrays[2]={"hello", "world"};
```

This is now an array of 2 char pointers pointing 2 strings

`*(arrays[0]+0)` or `arrays[0][0]` would refer to the first character in `1st` string

`*(arrays[0]+1)` or `arrays[0][1]` would refer to the second character in `1st` string

`*(arrays[1]+0)` or `arrays[1][0]` would refer to the first character in `2nd` string

`*(arrays[1]+1)` or `arrays[1][1]` would refer to the second character in `2nd` string

Answer (score 0):

You can also use enum in c

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whbyts4t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
  enum DAY            /* Defines an enumeration type    */
 {
    saturday,       /* Names day and declares a       */
    sunday = 0,     /* variable named workday with    */ 
    monday,         /* that type                      */
    tuesday,
    wednesday,      /* wednesday is associated with 3 */
    thursday,
    friday
 } workday;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *a[50]={"Hello", "World"};

char *a[256]={ ['H'] = "Hello", ['W'] = "World"};  \\ c99 -extension
```

Char is a perfectly valid type for indexing an array. At least for the first 128 elements. For the next 128 elements not to be interpreted negative values char has to unsigned.

Comment: I don't agree with this, specially because this is a hack and also because the person who started this post is just starting to learn C pointers. This is not good advice to a novice programmer. In your hack, you are allocating 256 memory positions with "fixed" keys (one for each ASCII position) where you only need 2 of them in this case. Also, there are several ASCII values that you will never use, I am sure. You could limit this range by changing 256 to 87 (ASCII code for 'W') but then again this is a limiting hack because you cannot use 'w' (ASCII code 119) or other values for instance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your string array declaration is incorrect. Under gcc, this gives the following error:

```
error: excess elements in char array initializer          
error: (near initialization for ‘arrays’)
```

because you are declaring **one** char string with 50 elements (each element is a char) and you are initializing it with **two** strings.

Now if you change to

```
char *arrays[2] = {"hello", "world"};
```

you are saying you have 2 pointers on your array: one pointer points to the "hello" string, and the other pointer to the string "world". You can see this is true by printing the value they point to:

```
printf("array content: %s - %s\n", arrays[0], arrays[1]);
```

This will print

```
array content: hello - world
```

Now if you want to index by a literal instead of a number, I think the most simple approach is to create a map where you can assign a character key to the string you want. See the answer given by hmjd (notice `bsearch()` is given by `stdlib.h` so have to include this header on your source code).

Please post your doubts or difficulties if you have them, I am sure we can help.